# MySQL list rows order by stars and also add rand()?

Tags: php

I successfully list rows, order by stars (3 stars first, 2 stars after and 1 star moreafter). However, I need to add rand. It should randomly show rows which have same stars.

```
select * from people order by stars desc limit 50
```

Here is how the table looks like:

```
id | name | stars
__________________
1---John---starstarstar
2---Mary---starstarstar
3---Tedy---starstarstar
4---Liam---starstar
5---Bery---starstar
```

What is the correct way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY stars DESC, RAND() LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: you can give multiple rows to order by, like the phone book orders by lastname, then first name

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `RAND()`.

```
select * from people order by RAND();
```

Comment: But that will rand all. I need to rand ones which has same stars. So that way the first 3 will rand from each other. And other star groups rand each other.

Comment: select * from people order by stars desc, RAND() limit 50